# Element with font-size less than 1em does not cover parent element

Tags: css, font-size

A child element with a font-size less than 1 is not the same size as its parent.

Why does the child element not cover the parent element completely?
Shouldn't be the parent size the same as child size?

It seems that the height of parent is calculated by the font-size of 1em.
Setting parent to `display:inline-block` also does not work.

```html
<span id="parent" style="background: blue; font-size: 10rem;">
  <span id="child" style="background: red; font-size: 0.7em">text</span>
</span>
```

Comment: What's surprising about a child element not completely covering its parent element?  That's happening all over the page you're looking at right now.  (Most of those cases involve block elements, not inline elements, but still ....)

Comment: If you do not specify a size (height, width) for an element, the size will be calculated by its children. But in that case the parent element is larger than its children without any height, margins, borders or paddings.

Comment: Well no, not for inline, non-replaced elements.  [The spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins) says: "The height of the content area should be **based on the font**, but this specification does not specify how." (Emphasis added.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `span` is a subset of flow which is phrasing content whereas for instance a `div` is flow content.  Here if we uncomment the CSS for `display: block;` it turns it into flow content and covers the container as "flow";

The following reference has a "visual" of some categories.

Reference for elements of content category: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories

Note the second gives it the nearly the same as a `div`

```css
#parent {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 10rem;
}

#child {

  background-color: red;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  /* uncomment display to see flow content */
/* display:block; */
}
```

```html
<span id="parent">
  <span id="child">text</span>
</span>
```

uncommented:

```css
#parent {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 10rem;
}

#child {

  background-color: red;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  /* uncomment display to see flow content */
 display:block; 
}
```

```html
<span id="parent">
  <span id="child">text</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Not a super "great" description perhaps but I hope you get the gist of this

Comment: Thank you, really interesting. The only problem is that your solution becomes a block element. If you add display: inline-block to parent, the child has the same sizes as the child and being inline.

Comment: Sizing including box-sizing is somewhat hard to grasp for CSS at times I would agree.  The best way I found was to create simple CSS and try some things out because I am a visual learner it became more clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

1.) `span` elements are `inline` elements. Their `line-height`(which in this case *is* their height) depends on the their font-size, so their actual height depends on their `font-size`, unless they have a `display` setting of `block`.

2.) `rem` is relative to the `font-size` defined for `html` - if there is no rule for that, there will be a browser setting.

3.) `em` is relative to the `font-size` for the element itself. If the `font-size` for a `span` is defined in `em` units, it will depend on its parent elements `font-size` setting. In your case the parent has a setting relative to `html`, the child has a setting relative to the parent, so NO, it's height won't be the same as the parent's height, but 0.7 times as much, i.e. only 70% of the parent height.

Comment: Good explanation to help understand this concept well verbally.

Comment: 1) Setting parent to inline-block is not working too.